# Buttons in activity not working properly on orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout

One testing the code of orientation & layout changes:

The main StartActivity contains 3 buttons (button1, button2, button3) & a liner layout containing space for Fragment.

When button1 is clicked the fragment shows the fragment1; Button2 shows fragment2 etc.

**Portrait**: (Filename- layout/activity_start.xml)

[image]

**Landscape**: (Filename- layout-land/activity_start.xml)
[image]

Issues:

1. When I change the orientation the buttons behave abnormally. They dont work on the first click. Only after I click then twice, then the work.
2. This StartActivity gets created every time the orientation is changed. (Toast in onCreate() gets poped-up)

I simply want that when the orientation changes: The layout should change accordingly & all the components of the activity like buttons should work as intended.
And the activity should not get recreated.

Code:

**StartActivity.java**

```
public class StartActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "StartActivity";
    private Fragment newFragment;
    private Button b1, b2, b3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

            Toast.makeText(this, "onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
            b1.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
            b2.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
            b3.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);

            FragmentManager fm = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

            StartFragment startFragment = new StartFragment();
            ft.add(R.id.selectedfragment, startFragment);
            ft.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }

    }

    private OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.button1:
                    newFragment = new Fragment1();
                    break;
                case R.id.button2:
                    newFragment = new Fragment2();
                    break;
                case R.id.button3:
                    newFragment = new Fragment3();
                    break;
                default:
                    newFragment = new StartFragment();
                    break;
                }

                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.selectedfragment, newFragment);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            }
        }
    };
}
```

**Section of Manifest.xml**

```
<activity
    android:name="com.ri.fragmenttest.StartActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: It is possible to stop your Activity being destroyed, but please ignore anyone who suggests that you do.  The problem is that if you do, you will not learn how to use the Activity lifecyle and in turn, you will not correctly use `onCreate()`, `onResume()` and `onPause()`.  This will leave you with a handful of bugs that most inexperienced developers don't even know about, let alone fix.  Read the Activity lifecycle documentation, then come back.  You will have either have fixed your problem or have a different question.

Comment: BTW, the immediate problem is nothing more than your landscape layout needs fixing and you haven't shown that so we can't help.

Comment: @Simon Code uploaded @ https://github.com/rahulsaini8/FragmentTest

Comment: Please edit your question.  The manifest and code you've shown are not relevant so you can remove this.  Simply show the landscape layout XML.  Sorry, but I don't go following links to see code. It's not how SO works.

Comment: @Simon Edited.. landscape layout xml added

Answer (score 0):

Your root LinearLayout is horizontal and it contains another LinearLayout which is vertical.

Therefore, your buttons are stacked on top of each other in a LinearLayout which is horizontally arranged.

Just change the inner layout to horizontal.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/Snow"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".StartActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical" >      <----- HERE
```

Comment: No... I want them to arranged like this only. The image I have shown that is my intended layout & layout rendering is working fine. But the buttons are not.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood the question - or actually, I didn't read it properly.  I'll take a look at the code again.